# Create Dynamic dropdowns with no blanks

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a dropdown on sheet1 from data on sheet10.  I cannot add a new column on sheet10, so I need to dynamically create the dropdown. There will be at least 1500 rows on Sheet10, but the dropdown needs to only list Column2 if the column4 matches a value on Sheet1!A1.

Ideally, the pulldown will concatenate the two Columns (e.g. "Column2(Column4)" but that is gravy.

I've tried several similar answers on this sight, but most require creating a column of the subset, then creates Formula:Name, then Data validation.  I've tried making the NAME item WITHOUT creating the helper column using FILTER and OFFSET and some others...

Sheet1:A1 = My Department

Sheet1!B3:B500 "MyNewDropList" Data validation.

Sheet 10!

```
     REF DOC    TASK    DATE        ORG
     -------    ------  --------    -------
     DOC 1      TASK 1  1/1/2000    My Department
     DOC 1      TASK 2  1/1/2000    
     DOC 1      TASK 3  1/1/2000    My Department
     DOC 1      TASK 4  1/1/2000    
     DOC 1      TASK 5  1/1/2000    Your Department
```

I would like to have a dynamic dropdown on Sheet1!B2:B550 that will include the values in SHeet10!B2:1500 if the "ORG" = the value in Sheet1:A1  (In this case "My Department"  If possible, I would like to include ORG in the dropdown.

With the values above, I would need the pulldown in SHeet1! Column B, to show:
TASK1
TASK3

Or better would be:
TASK 1 (My Department)
TASK 3 (My Department)

The dropdown needs to be dynamic so that if The value any value in ORG is changed to "My Department", then the dropdown would need to include the new TASK meeting the My Department criteri

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add a column, I've decided to create a separate worksheet.  From here I've created my dynamic list, created a name (excluding the blank lines).  I now have my pulldowns working, but was hoping to do so without creating the separate worksheet.